# LINEのメッセージ取得

Tags: api, line

自分が普段使っているLINE ID（BOT用ではない）で、既存グループでのメッセージを文字列として、別のプログラムへ通知することは可能でしょうか？

message APIのホームページを見ても、BOTを前提としていると私は現時点理解しており、ひょっとして無理なのかなと思っていますが、詳しい方に尋ねて確証を得たいです。

どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

messaging apiではその要件は満たせないですね。
グループの会話を通知したければ、グループにボットを追加する必要があります。